# Live render of text in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I would like to make a textarea and a div near it similar to what you use in the "ask question" page here in stackoverflow.
You type a text in the textarea and the text is rendered live under the textarea.
I'd like to make this to convert "live" some codes like "a024" typed in the textarea to symbols in the div.
Do I need to use javascript to get this feature?
Thanks.

Comment: oh you mean 4 spaces become code ...like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That was called DHTML for Dynamic HTML at the beginning of JavaScript.
You will have to use Javascript to create this behavior.

You can get the value of an element with something like:

```
var source = document.getElementById("sourceTextarea").value;
```

and set text in a destination element with something like:

```
document.getElementById("destinationDiv").innerText = "some text";
```

In your HTML you will have to use :

```
<textarea id="sourceTextarea"></textarea><div id="destinationDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need Javascript to achieve this goal.

You can make use of the 'onkeyup' property of the textarea to bind a javascript function the keyup event.

Once you do this, you can process the texarea value to replace whatever you need to.

```js
function updateMyDiv() {
    var myTextarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    myDiv.innerHTML = myTextarea.value;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="myTextarea" onkeyup="updateMyDiv()">
</textarea>

<div id="myDiv">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```